# Does a water leaking make the engine heat faster?

Tags: engine, radiator, heat

I have a Range Rover classic 1993 which is heating very fast even if I just drive for 10 min, the heat is not rising too much but I used to drive this Range Rover before and especially in winter season and never seen the heat meter rising unless I drive for a long period.

This heating came at the same time with water leaking that I noticed on a pipe (not too much to be noticed), so my question is does this water leaking have anything to do with the heating ? or is it something else ?

Comment: Do you have enough coolant in there?

Comment: @TimoGeusch Yes I have enough coolant, the strange thing is this happened after a mechanic cleaned up my radiator which had rust in its water.

Comment: Depending on where the leak is there could be a common cause for the over heating and the leak.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where is the water leaking from? If it is from any part of the cooling system then yes, your engine's cooling system will not work as efficiently so it will heat up faster.

My guess is that clearing out the rust also exposed a leak somewhere in the radiator.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, there's a pipe leaking I don't know what it is, and the water tank makes a sound like it's sucking air from the outside and when opened the water level rises and then it overflows.

Comment: the overflowing bit is normal, that is why you should never remove the lid when it is hot. The rest is not normal.

Comment: If air is being sucked in, then it will probably over heat.